# Emojis on textarea does not save post

Tags: php

I have a commenting system and when its just text, no problem - it is saved to the database. When I add a  (for instance), then no comment is saved to the database? Nothing is saving, when there is an emoji.

What can I do to allow emojis?

The "message" is where I am saving the actual comment and where there should be an emoji.

[image]

Comment: What is the error you are getting? this is mostly related to the database also, can you please add your PHP and the comment table structure.

Comment: @ROOT I get no errors. It behaves just as if the comment was added but nothing is in the database, when I include an emoji

Comment: Ah, so we are talking about `message` field, right? can you alert the table structure and modify the encoding for `message` field to be `utf8mb4_general_ci`? `utf8_general_ci` can't handle emoji characters.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to update the charset and potentially collation. I'm assuming you're using MySQL. This is very confusing, but in MySQL the UTF8 charset isn't actually UTF8, but a mysql's proprietary charset that is largely similar to the actual UTF8, but lacks some characters.
The way to handle it is to switch to the actual UTF8, which in the world of mysql is called utf8mb4_general_ci. You can do so by running

`ALTER DATABASE <you db name> CHARACTER SET utf8mb4_general_ci COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci;`
(this will affect only the new tables that you create)

and

`ALTER TABLE <you existing table name> CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4_general_ci;`
(this will update an already existing table, although the emojis that you already lost cannot be recovered)